# test -L command returns different error code when called from prompt than from inside the script

Tags: bash, zsh

I have one folder and one link to the folder:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 xxx staff    9 Dec 12 08:59 _myOrg -> ../_myOrg
drwxr-xr-x   33 xxx staff 1.1K Apr 12 16:47 xxx
```

when I run `test -L _myOrg` and then `echo $?` and then `test -L xxx` and then `echo $?` I get – as expected – `0` and `1` respectively.

However, when I run it from the script below:

```
#!/bin/zsh

pushd $tyc > /dev/null

for d in */ ; do
    if test -L d 
    then
        echo 0
    else
        echo 1
    fi
done

popd > /dev/null
```

I'm getting:

```
1
1
```

and not expected

```
0
1
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Should it not be $d when used as an argument?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö no difference

Comment: @dawg `"$tyc"` – no change, adding `echo "$d"` resulted in: `_myOrg/` `1` `xxx/` `1`

Comment: @oguzismail: I think Bash is a legit tag since this issue is a fairly general shell issue...

Comment: I don't understand why it's tagged _bash_ and _zsh_. If your interactive shell is bash, then you would execute two different kinds of `test` in both cases: In the script, the zsh builtin `test` and in bash the bash builtin `test`, but in this case specify explicitly which _test_ is used in both cases, and also the shell version(s).

Comment: Asides from this: Your command `test -L d` applies _test_ to a file named `d`. I guess you mean `test -L $d`.

Comment: @user1934428: Because the issue seen, a trailing `/` throws off `test`, is shared between those two shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
% tree
.
├── xxx
├── yyy -> /tmp/tgt
└── zzz
```

And:

```
% ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 dawg  staff  64 Apr 25 16:38 xxx
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dawg  staff   8 Apr 25 16:45 yyy -> /tmp/tgt
drwxr-xr-x  2 dawg  staff  64 Apr 25 17:24 zzz
```

You are using the following glob:

```
for d in */ ; do
    [[ -L "$d" ]] && echo "$d is a link" || echo "$d is not a link"
done
```

Which results in:

```
xxx/ is not a link
yyy/ is not a link
zzz/ is not a link
```

Notice the trailing `/`. Now change the glob:

```
for d in * ; do
    [[ -L "$d" ]] && echo "$d is a link" || echo "$d is not a link"
done
```

And it works:

```
xxx is not a link
yyy is a link
zzz is not a link
```

Or use your glob and remove the final `/` in the test:

```
for d in */ ; do
    [[ -L "${d: : -1}" ]] && echo "$d is a link" || echo "$d is not a link"
done
```

Or, test to see if there is a trailing `/` and remove it if so. This now works with both styles of globs:

```
for d in */ ; do
    td="${d%/}"
    [[ -L "$td" ]] && echo "$d is a link" || echo "$d is not a link"
done
```

Either of those prints:

```
xxx/ is not a link
yyy/ is a link
zzz/ is not a link
```

Note:

- You also need the sigil -- the `$` part -- to reference the value in the looped variable. The way you have written it, `test` is attempting to test a literal `d` and silently failing if the file is not found.
- You should generally use `"double quotes"` around variables in the shell unless you have a good reason not to do so (like around a glob) or the result is subject to further processing by the shell resulting in something different than you are expecting.
- A path with the trailing `/` refers to that paths CONTENTS - not the path itself. This is why `yyy/` is not a link but `yyy` is a link. See [filepath misconceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Path_(computing)#Filepath_Misconceptions).